# Why do I get errors when I link to a library, but not when I build it?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I'm working on an external module for a c++ library (ITK), which I'm building with cmake and make (I'm on an Ubuntu VM).

Let's say there is an error in the code, such as redefinition of a method.  In this case, the library builds without errors with `cmake ../src && make && sudo make install`, but I get an error when I try to link a project against the library.

Why is it that the errors don't stop the library build?  Is there something fundamentally different about these scenarios that causes `make` to behave differently?

I'm fairly new to c++ (and to compiled languages generally)--I imagine there is something fundamental about the build process that I'm not understanding.  I found it difficult to search for this--searching for "c++ library build no error" gives me a lot of threads on c++ library build errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting at link time exactly?

Comment: Well, in the method redefinition example, something like `error: redefinition of ‘void itk::PhaseDerivativeVarianceImageFilter<TInputImage, TOutputImage>::PrintSelf(std::ostream&, itk::Indent) const’`

Comment: Generally I understand where these errors are coming from once I get them--I just don't understand why the compiler doesn't pick them up when I build the library.

Comment: How are you building the library? Is it a static library or a dynamic library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, libraries are simply collections of compiled code - object files. As a rule the linkage errors that you're seeing will only be picked up when you create an executable at which point the linker will try to ensure that all symbols used in your executable can be resolved with the libraries that you're linking against.

If the definition of a symbol (function, constant etc) either cannot be found or is ambiguous (i.e. can be found in more than one place, then linking will fail.

Comment: Thanks--I think the fundamental thing I didn't understand is that when building a library it looks at each "object" (such as a method definition) separately, and doesn't try to relate them to one another.  So if I had had plain-old invalid c++ (like a stray backslash or something) I would have gotten an error.  This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

While linking, it checks for cross-references, symbols (functions, identifiers etc) definition and call or use gets binded in static linking (dynamic linking is different where cross-referencing may not be done as this is deferred linking). Library is a simple collection of function or identification definition, doesn't do cross-referencing.